# How to multilanguage desktop application using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi All I am very new to c# .I have searched google how to make multi language calender using c# but i have not found any results. I need to make calender in these three languages any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a **Desktop app**

you have to change the current culture

```
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr")
 System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
```

check this link [http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19)

For a **Web Page**

simply change the page culture and UI culture
to get The Islamic calendar change culture to

```
<%@ Page UICulture="ar" Culture="ar-SA" %>
```

Gregorian : change back to english

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en" Culture="en-US" %>
```

Comment: Hi many Thanks I am Doing it in desktop based application using c# not asp

Comment: oops , I saw "asp.net" tag so I expected it's a web page

Comment: Can you now say how to do that in c#